# Laravel Mix warrnings/erros compared to CDN

Tags: javascript, laravel, cdn, laravel-mix

I am implementing [`<model-viewer>`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/model-viewer), but I wanted it to be precompiled with the built in ***Laravel-Mix***, however when I include the CDN [https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js] there are no errors or whatsoever and everything is smooth. If I build this package with ***Laravel-Mix*** I get bunch of warrnings and errors: [image: console.log()]

I tried the following approaches inside the ***Laravel-Mix*** but none of the worked successfully. They all return the same error.

```
1. require("@google/model-viewer");

2. window.modelViewer = require("@google/model-viewer");

3. import * as ModelViewerElement from '@google/model-viewer';

4. import ModelViewerElement from '@google/model-viewer';

5. import { ModelViewerElement } from '@google/model-viewer';
```

Comment: Is the CDN script tag there when you try to include it in your build process?

Comment: @Daedalus no, that was my main goal to eliminate the CDN and only use the Laravel-Mix

Comment: No idea then based on provided information.  My only 'guess' thought is that somehow, the code for the tag is being executed prior to your build step somewhere; that's what the error seems to suggest.